# How do I bring back my firefox bookmark bar

Tags: firefox

I had a bookmark bar yesterday but today it is gone. I read the help and it says to use Menu->Customize->Toolbars. But there is no Toolbars under Customize. There is a Toolbar menu but that is not the tool bar.

Comment: Right click in the empty space beside a Tab, select Menu Bar, and then in the Menu, select Bookmarks. Several possibilities there.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that the button is at the bottom of the page

Comment: It sort of answers the question, but would be much better with a screenshot.